# Highlight fields in form that have been modified

Tags: html, angularjs

I was wondering if someone can give me a general guideline or example for the following. I have created a form with several input box fields. When a user inputs something, the field highlights it orange. When a user goes to another field, the highlight goes away and the new box gets highlighted. When the user hits "save" button, the form gets saved. When the user hits "modify" button, it allows them to change the values in the fields. However, this time I would like to have the highlighted box stay highlighted on all the fields that have been changed (and obviously the fields that are not touched remain not highlighted). Is there anyway someone can send me a tutorial or create a quick example to demonstrate this? I am using Angular 1.5 and used Bootstrap to create a simple form.
Thank you

Comment: Are you able to add a class to any fields that are edited?

Comment: Angular adds an `ng-dirty` css class to fields that the user has interacted with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use `$touched` property to know whether user clicked on that particular form field.

```
Ex:
custFrom.inputName.$touched
```

To know actual value modification use `$dirty` in the same way

```
Ex:
custFrom.inputName.$dirty
```

Please find working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tAK7KSG3WnMY9MOHN1TK?p=preview)

Comment: this plunker is fine but what about resetting the highlight if the value of the field returns to its previous state? (e.g. if it was empty to start with, any change is highlighted, but deleting the change should go back to unhighlighted)...